# SpriteKit: fade out SKNode - children shines through

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, fadeout, skaction

I have a SKSpriteNode which I fade out with `baseNode.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5))`

The sprite has one Child. Also a SKSpriteNode. (The red block in the image)

While the **baseNode** fades out there is the contour of die child node.

What is the best way to avoid this and fade out the whole node with its children **simultaneously**? I want to play a Texture Animation in the child Node. So flatten is no solution.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to just fade the child node?

Comment: No, I want to fade out both Nodes simultaneously. So that it looks like I just fade out the parent node.

Answer (score 6):

This question raised my curiosity. I have a solution, but, for lack of my knowledge of Swift, have written it in Objective-C. It is very simple, however, and porting should be of no problem to you.

**The trick is to *flatten* the entire node into a single texture and fade that instead.**

I have implemented this using a Category. The code below replaces the `texture` property of an SKSpriteNode with a flattened texture. The key method is [-textureFromNode:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/textureFromNode:) inside the `SKView` class.

```
@interface SKSpriteNode (Fading)

- (void)flattenForFading;

@end
```

...

```
#import "SKSpriteNode+Fading.h"

@implementation SKSpriteNode (Fading)

- (void)flattenForFading {
  SKTexture *flattenedContents = [self.scene.view textureFromNode:self];

  /// Copy the children array, so when we are iterating the removing doesn't cause any problems
  NSArray *children = [self.children copy];

  for (SKNode *child in children) {
    [child removeFromParent];
  }

  self.texture = flattenedContents;
  self.size = self.texture.size;
}

@end
```

In the case of a non-SKSpriteNode case you can just add a new SKSpriteNode as a child of the node being flattened. Animation inside the node is not supported since you're baking a single texture. Instead of removing all children, you could just *hide* them as well of course. If you would add an extra property for the removed texture, you could even save the internal state and revert this method's effect with a `-unflatten` method. But that goes beyond the scope of your question.

I took this screenshot in the Simulator. Note that the node counter corresponds with the 3 faded SKSpriteNodes, 1 SKLabelNode and 1 flattened sprite (SKSpriteNode).

[image: Non-flattened vs. flattened SKSpriteNode]

Comment: Really a great solution. But I want to play an texture animation with the child node. But I really like your answer, so I will reward it if there comes no other solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to call the same action on the node's children as well.

```
baseNode.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5))

for node in baseNode.children as! [SKSpriteNode]
{
    node.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.5))
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this. But there is still the child shining through. I guess it is because the alpha of both nodes is added. So if the fade out is at 0.5 they both together still have 1.0 alpha.

Comment: If the child is the same color and is not supposed to be seen, why not use clearColor?

Comment: The height of the child is higher than the visible part because is plays a texture animation over the red bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parent SKEffectNode that wraps both the base node and the child node and do the fade on the effect node itself.

Even if you aren't using filters or other features of SKEffectNode, it renders its children in a private framebuffer, so it ends up doing what the flatten suggestion was trying to do, but it will take care of everything for you, even if the children are animating every frame, like you are going for in your example.

For performance, you can also disable the extra cost of using a parent SKEffectNode by setting shouldEnableEffects = false, and only turn this on/off when needing to do the fade.

Answer (score 1):

for transitions between screens a cool effect is to have a black node covering the entire screen, and then fading it out. I came up with the following: *Swift 3*

```
import SpriteKit

override func didEnter(from previousState: GKState?) {

let blackNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.black, size: scene.size)
blackNode.position = CGPoint(x: scene.size.width / 2, y: scene.size.height / 2)
blackNode.zPosition = Layer.top.rawValue
scene.worldNode.addChild(blackNode)
blackNode.alpha = 1.0
blackNode.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.5)) }
```

I was struggling to find the solution to this, so I hope this helps someone out there.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fadeOutWIthDuration() on the child nodes, why don't you use colorizeWithColor(_:colorBlendFactor:duration:).

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/colorizeWithColor:colorBlendFactor:duration:

> colorizeWithColor(_:colorBlendFactor:duration:)
>
> Creates an animation
>   that animates a sprite’s color and blend factor.
>
> Declaration
>
> SWIFT
>
> class func colorizeWithColor(_ color: UIColor,
>               colorBlendFactor colorBlendFactor: CGFloat,
>                       duration sec: NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction
>
> Parameters
>
> color  The new color for the sprite.
>
> colorBlendFactor   The new blend factor for the sprite.
>
> sec    The duration of the animation.
>
> Return Value A new action object.
>
> Discussion 
>   This action can only be executed by an SKSpriteNode object.
>   When the action executes, the sprite’s color and colorBlendFactor
>   properties are animated to their new values.
>
> This action is not reversible; the reverse of this action does
>   nothing.
>
> Import Statement
>
> SWIFT
>
> import SpriteKit
>
> Availability Available in iOS
>
> 7.0 and later.

Comment: I used this `SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.clearColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 1)` but the child still shines through.